# Match String Pattern

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have to compare two strings containing only `P`, `F` or `*`, say `PPFFP` AND `P**F*`, `*` means it doesn't care about what comes at this place it may be F or P. So in this scenario output will be true for above two strings.

Comment: You can use a regex with a character class.

Comment: Please tell us more about the problem.  You want to "compare two strings"--where do those two strings come from?  Is one of them a known constant, or could both of them come from some input source?  If both can come from input, can only one of them contain `*`, or both?

Comment: both come from input and both can have `*`

Comment: Is the length of the strings fixed to 5?

Comment: no limit on length

Answer (score 3):

If only one of the strings contains `*`, you could use a regular expression. Just replace every `*` with `[PF]`:

```
String s = "PPFFP";
if (s.matches("P[PF][PF]F[PF]") {
    ...
}
```

A more elementary method allowing `*`in both strings would be:

```
public static boolean matches( String s1, String s2 ) {
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++ ) {
        if (s1.charAt(i) != '*' &&
            s2.charAt(i) != '*' &&
            s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could also do `"[FP]+"`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis: I don't think so. If there is no wildcard at the position in one string, it does matter which of the characters is in the other string.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't fully understand what the OP wanted at first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague.  However, let's assume you need to write a method

```
public boolean matches(String left, String right)
```

where `left` contains only P and F, while `right` could also contain `*` to match any character.

You can do this by converting the right argument into a regex, where `*` is replaced by `[PF]` to match either P or F:

```
public boolean matches(String left, String right) {
    String regex = right.replace("*", "[PF]");
    return left.matches(regex);
}
```

In Java, regexes are just `String` values, and it's completely acceptable for a regex to be a string that was created by some other expression.

If both `left` and `right` can contain `*`, see Frank's answer.  (**Note: this appears to be your situation, but I posted my answer before seeing your comment.**)  There are "clever" ways to do this by creating a regex, but I believe it makes the code too messy, so I prefer the loop approach.  I think this will work, though:

```
public boolean matches(String left, String right) {
    String regex = right.replace("*", "#")
                        .replace("P", "[P\\*]")
                        .replace("F", "[F\\*]")
                        .replace("#", "[PF\\*]");
    return left.matches(regex);
}
```

I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, this might be what you are looking for:

```
String input_1 = "*PF*P";
String input_2 = "P**F*";
char[] input_1_chars = input_1.toCharArray();
char[] input_2_chars = input_2.toCharArray();

if(input_1.length() != input_2.length()){ // If two strings are not equal
    System.out.println("FALSE");   
}
else{
    for(int i=0;i<input_2.length();i++){
        if(input_2.charAt(i) == '*'){
            input_1_chars[i]='*'; // Copy asterisk from input 2 to indices of input 1.
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<input_1.length();i++){
        if(input_1.charAt(i) == '*'){
            input_2_chars[i]='*'; // Copy asterisk from input 1 to indices of input 2.
        }
    }

    input_1 = String.valueOf(input_1_chars);// Convert char array back to string.
    input_2 = String.valueOf(input_2_chars);
    if(input_1.equals(input_2)){
        System.out.println("TRUE");// If strings are equal then print True
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("FALSE");//else false
    }   
}
```

`INPUT:       OUTPUT: 
 PPF*P        TRUE
 P**F*`

`INPUT:       OUTPUT: 
 PPFPP        FALSE
 P**F*`

Comment: Looks like this will work, except that you really should quit if you find the lengths are unequal.  The way you've written it, it will output FALSE and then try to go on and eventually throw an exception.  Also, now that the OP has said that both strings can contain `*`, I think you need to fix it so that both strings are converted to char arrays, and characters in both arrays are set to `*` if necessary.  I think Frank's solution is more efficient, but this is a method that could be useful in solving similar problems.  Also you misspelled "asterisk".

Comment: Okay, but what I understood from the OP is that only second string contains asterisk. Anyways will update the new code. Thank you for pointing that out.